# Building a powerful virtual machine over many clustered micro scale cloud instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, cloud, cluster-computing

My question is very short.

Is it possible to cluster many free-tier `t2.micro` scale AWS EC2 instances together, and then build up one single powerful virtual server over them? A new machine using the CPUs, Memories and HDDs of the clustered machines as one single hardware and one single OS?

Whether this would be a sufficient server in the end, or not, I still want to know if this is possible in practice.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** You cannot combine several Amazon EC2 instances into one larger virtual machine. Well, **you actually *can* do this** -- by choosing a larger Instance Type. You then get a virtual machine with more CPU, RAM and disk acting as one virtual machine. But AWS does that for you -- you can't do it.

The [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is provided to allow you to try AWS services. It is not intended as a production platform.

The Free Tier includes (in the first 12 months of your AWS account):

- 750 hours per month of Windows t2.micro instance usage
- 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro instance usage

This means you could run one Linux instance for a month, or two instances for half a month, etc. It gives you 750 hours per month of EC2 time.

Once the free hours are consumed, you will be billed for services according to the normal price.

Comment: It's "No" as in there is nothing that can combine multiple virtual machines into one larger virtual machine. You would simply create a larger virtual machine. Hey, if you're looking at power vs cost, take a look at [Spot Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/) for EC2 instances. You can get up to 90% off the price of instances with a (small-ish) risk of them being terminated when demand increases.